# How to change the bounds of this iterated integral?

Tags: integration

How can I switch the order so I integrate by y first in the following double integral:

$\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{\sqrt(y)}{x\over\sqrt{3x^2+y}}dxdy$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are integrating over the region $0\le y\le 9$, $0\le x\le \sqrt{y}$.

This can be rewritten as $0\le x\le 3$, $x^2\le y\le 9$, so

$$\int_{0}^{9}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}} \frac{x}{\sqrt{3x^2+y}}dxdy = \int_0^3 \int_{x^2}^9 \frac{x}{\sqrt{3x^2+y}}dydx$$

Comment: Can you please explain how you got the new bounds?

Comment: You first want to write down the inequalities which the old bounds imply for $x$ and $y$. You notice that the inequality for $x$ depends on $y$. Now you want to transform them into an equivalent pair of inequalities where the inequality for $x$ doesn't depend on $y$ anymore, but instead the one for $y$ depends on $x$. So you go $0\le x\le \sqrt{y}\le \sqrt{9}=3$ and you have the one for $x$. Now the one for $y$ follows b/c $0\le x\le \sqrt{y}$ is equivalent to $0\le x^2\le y$, and we also know $y\le 9$, so the inequality for $y$ is $x^2\le y\le 9$.

Comment: Do a few example and you'll quickly get the hang of it.